# Would using transactions in a Celery task in Django application cause problems?

Tags: python, django, transactions, celery, django-celery

I have a set of celery tasks that I've written. Each of these tasks take a — just an example — author id as a parameter and for each of the books for the author, it fetches the latest price and stores it in the database.

I'd like to add transactions to my task by adding Django's 
`@transaction.commit_on_success` decorator to my tasks. If any task crashes, I'd like the whole task to fail and nothing to be saved to the database.

I have a dozen or so celery workers that check the prices of books for a author and I'm wondering if this simple transactional logic would cause locking and race conditions in my Postgres database.

I've dug around and found this project called [django-celery-transactions](https://github.com/chrisdoble/django-celery-transactions) but I still haven't understood the real issue behind this and what this project tried to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is that in your Django view the DB transaction is not committed until the view has exited if you apply the decorator. Inside the view before it returns and triggers the commit you may invoke tasks that expect the DB transaction to already be committed i.e. for those entries to exist in the DB context.

In order to guard against this race condition (task starting before your view and consequently  transaction finished) you can either manually manage it or use the module you mentioned which handles it automatically for you.

The example where it might fail for instance in your case is if you are adding a new author and you have a task that fetches prices for all/any of its books. Should the task execute before the commit for the new author transaction is done, your task will try to fetch Author with an id that does not yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several things including: the transaction isolation level of your database, how frequently you check for price updates, and how often you expect prices to change. If, for example, you were making a very large number of updates per second to [stock standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/transaction-iso.html) PostgreSQL, you might get different results executing the same select statement multiple times in a transaction.

Databases are optimized to handle concurrency so I don't think this is going to be a problem for you; especially if you don't open the transaction until after fetching prices (i.e. use a context manager rather than decorating the task). If — for some reason — things get slow in the future, optimize then (fetch prices less frequently, tweak database configuration, etc.).

As for you other question: django-celery-transactions aims to prevent race conditions between Django and Celery. One example is if you were to pass the primary key of a newly created object to a task: the task may attempt to retrieve the object before the view's transaction has been committed. Boom!